# Value not set in contact form 7 plugin of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

I'm using the contact form 7 plugin in wordpress and I have generated a text field like this:

```
 [text* your-name 30/ "<?php $_GET['name']; ?>"]
```

I have to set value of input name which comes from another form with GET method but it's not worked.  Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is another hook as php might not be available here. read this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/ it gives the exact solution.